Calculate 6 months forward date from a dataframe of dates
I have below code
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
date = pd.to_datetime(['2001-01-01', '2003-01-01'])
date + relativedelta(months = +6)

Basically I am trying to calculate 6 months ahead date from a dataframe of dates.
Above code is failing.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'relativedelta'

Could you please help to correct this code?

You can't use Python's datetime utils with Pandas.
You should use Pandas' DateOffset:
date = pd.to_datetime(['2001-01-01', '2003-01-01'])
date + pd.DateOffset(months = +6)

Output:
DatetimeIndex(['2001-07-01', '2003-07-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

